# why i am getting black screen when running this .py and .kv script?

Tags: python, kivy

.py file
this is python code
When I start the program it gives me a blank, black screen. I used the python file for the functionality and the kv file for the properties of the objects. Py file:

```
    import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

    Builder.load_file('design.kv')

    class LoginScreen(Screen):
        pass

    class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
        pass

    class MainApp(App):
        def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    if __name__=="__main__":
        MainApp().run()
```

.kv file
this is kv script

```
     <LoginScreen>:
         GridLayout:
             cols:1
             GridLayout:
                 cols:1
                 Label:
                     text: "User Login"
                 TextInput:
                     hint_text: "Username"
                 TextInput:
                     hint_text: "Password"
                 Button:
                     text: "Login"


             GridLayout:
                 cols:2
                 Button:
                     text: "Forgot password"
                 Button:
                     text: "Sign Up"
     <RootWidget>:
         name: "Login_screen"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the file at the end of the script, and then return it inside the build method:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

kvfile = Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kvfile


if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Even after doing this i still got blank screen

Comment: Try to modify your kv file like this: https://prnt.sc/vc1z4t

Comment: I don't know why you gave a name to the ScreenManager, you don't usually do that. You want to give a name to the screens, so you can transition between them, not to ScreenManager itself